# Issue in build and install python3.2 in mac osx lion

Tags: python, installation, python-3.2

I using Mac OSX Lion and I could easily install python3.2 using DMG installer setup available in python.org site.
But i want to write some python-C functions and create a binary for it.
So for this purpose i tried to install python3.2 zip available in python.org site.

Instead stuck with installation errors when I use following install procedures

> ./configure --enable-framework
>   make
>   sudo make install

**Error:**

> gcc  -DPYTHONFRAMEWORK='"Python"' -o pythonw ./Tools/pythonw.c -I.. -I./../Include ../Python.framework/Versions/3.2/Python
>        /usr/bin/install -c -s pythonw "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/pythonw3.2"
>        /usr/bin/install -c -s pythonw "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python3.2"
>        ln -sf python3.2 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python3"
>        ln -sf pythonw3.2 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/pythonw3"
>        cd PythonLauncher && make install DESTDIR=
>        gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -o FileSettings.o -c ./FileSettings.m
>        In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:120,
>                    from ./FileSettings.h:9,
>                    from ./FileSettings.m:9:
>        /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSTask.h:75: error: syntax error before ‘^’ token
>        make[2]: *** [FileSettings.o] Error 1
>        make[1]: *** [install_PythonLauncher] Error 2
>        make: *** [frameworkinstallapps] Error 2

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to build your own Python just to build your own Python C extension modules?

Comment: Found the issue and installed python 3.2 in my mac lion os.  The issue was the GCC compiler. But I want to install it for 32 bit architecture. However it installed for 64 bit architecture. Any idea how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.  It seems very suspicious that you are seeing a syntax error on an Apple-supplied OS X header file.  What version of Xcode do you have installed and which C compiler are you using (`gcc --version`)?  Also, if your purpose is to build C extension modules there is normally no reason to build a Python from source.  The Distutils package in the Python standard library takes care of all the build issues for you and all the needed header files are included in the python.org binary installers for Mac OS X.

UPDATE: In your new comment you indicate you want to run Python as 32-bit.  The python.org 64-/32-bit installers for OS X are multi-architecture (or `universal`); each executable file contains executables for both arch x86_64 (64-bit) and for arch i386 (32-bit).  Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7 will prefer to run 64-bit executables where possible.  To launch 64-bit/32-bit Pythons in 32-bit mode, try:

```
arch -i386 python3.2
```

For example:

```
python3.2 -c "import sys;print(sys.maxsize)"
9223372036854775807
arch -x86_64 python3.2 -c "import sys;print(sys.maxsize)"
9223372036854775807
arch -i386 python3.2 -c "import sys;print(sys.maxsize)"
2147483647
```

Comment: I found the issue and updated with the comment above. Also Have you built the python? Which XCode did u use? For me wen i use Xcode 4.1 alone, there were issues with GCC, while i use 'make' command. But later i created a 10.4uSDK link using 3.1 Xcode's 10.5SDK installed some other place. Can i achieve it in some other way? if possible pls suggest me...